# Alter All Column Values using TRIM in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

> I want to modify (Remove all white spaces) all the values of Column
>   "Name" .
>
> How do I use TRIM and modify all column values of Name .
>
> Example :
>
> Before :  " rishi.ranka " After :   "rishi.ranka"
>
> Thank you very much in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the datatype of `name` column is `varchar` then don't need to use `rtrim` function the right side spaces will be automatically trim. use only [LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933237%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) only.

```
update tablename
set    name = ltrim(name)
where  <condition>;
```

Run this see the how it trims the right spaces automatically.

```
DECLARE @mytb table
(
name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @mytb VALUES ('   stackoverflow         ');

SELECT len(name) from @mytb;

SELECT ltrim(name),len(ltrim(name)) from @mytb;
```

Comment: tried but it didn't remove right side spaces so i used rtrim.

Comment: See this SELECT ltrim(name),len(ltrim(name)), len(ltrim(rtrim(name))),'a_'+ltrim(name)+'_a'

Answer (score 5):

Use a combination of [LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933237%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (Left Trim) & [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238471%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (Right Trim):

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [Name]=LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
```